# Combine two List<Map<String, String>> for unique list

Tags: apex, list, map

How can I combine two lists of maps so that only the unique values in the list remain?  I thought about doing some nested for loops to compare the two lists, but it seems a bit messy.  Is there a better way to do this.

Obviously just adding to the list doesn't give me unique values.
MapList.addAll(mapList2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Set<Map<String, String>>` can contain and deduplicate `Map<String, String>` by their contents. When working with `Set`, keep in mind how it [determines object identity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm):

> Uniqueness of all other non-primitive types is determined by comparing the objects’ fields.

As an illustration, you can do

```
Set<Map<String, String>> s = new Set<Map<String, String>>();

Map<String,String> m1 = new Map<String, String> {
    'Test' => 'Foo'
};

Map<String,String> m2 = new Map<String, String> {
    'Test' => 'Foo'
};

s.add(m1);
System.debug('s contains m2? ' + String.valueOf(s.contains(m2)));
```

You'll get back `true`; the two `Map` instances are considered equal because they have the same field values.

You can get a deduplicated `Set<Map<String, String>>` from a two `List<Map<String, String>>` objects by doing

```
Set<Map<String, String>> s = new Set<Map<String, String>>(myList);
s.addAll(myOtherList):
```